# How to get cookie in express typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, cookies

Thank you for coming here
i've been configing server by express and typescript
i did success to make cookie like this code

```
app.get('/',req: Request, res: Response) => {
    // res.cookie('park', 'juhong');
    return res.send('cookie!');
}))
```

but when i try to get cookie by cookie-parser it doesn't work

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser);
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
 console.log(req.cookies);
 return res.send('cookie!');
})
```

How to get cookie in express typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a cookie: `res.cookie('name', value, { httpOnly: true, expires: expire })`

get a cookie: `req.cookies['cookie-name']`

then in client version for example if you make a request with axios you need to enable property **withCredentials**